# PDO duplicate query doesnt duplicate

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i am currently making a cms and want to make a option where you can duplicate posts. how i do this is like following: on the archive page( where i fetch all the posts and display them in a table) i add a checkbox with the id of the post (post_id). then i have a select wrapper in a < form > with the option to duplicate, i then send it to my functions map where i check the select value in a switch.

if switchStatement == duplicate i make a query
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = :value"
:value is in this case post_id.

in the other function where i want to do the duping i have the following code:

```
function duplicateBulk($bulkQuery, $connection, $data){
    $statusNumber = 0;
        $duplicateStmnt = $connection->prepare($bulkQuery);
        $duplicateStmnt->execute($data);
        while($bulkResult = $duplicateStmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
            $post_title = $bulkResult['post_title'];
            $post_subtitle = $bulkResult['post_subtitle'];
            $post_author = $bulkResult['post_author'];
            $post_tag = $bulkResult['post_tags'];
            $post_date = date('d-m-y');
            $post_content = $bulkResult['post_content'];
            $post_id = $bulkResult['post_id'];
            $post_img= $bulkResult['post_img'];
            $post_thumb = $bulkResult['post_thumb'];
            $post_category_id = $bulkResult['post_category_id'];
            echo $post_title;
        
        $dataCl = [
            'post_id'           => $post_id,
            'post_author'       => $post_author,
            'post_title'        => $post_title,
            'post_subtitle'     => $post_subtitle,
            'post_tag'          => $post_tag,
            'post_date'         => $post_date,
            'post_content'      => $post_content,
            'post_img'          => $post_img,
            'post_thumb'        => $post_thumb,
            'post_category_id'  => $post_category_id,
            'post_status'       => $statusNumber
        ];
        $cloneQuery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO posts ( post_id, post_author, post_status, 
 post_tags, post_date, post_title, post_subtitle, post_content, post_category_id, post_img, 
 post_thumb ) VALUES ( :post_id, :post_author,:post_status, :post_tag, :post_date, 
  :post_title, :post_subtitle, :post_content, :post_category_id, :post_img, :post_thumb )";
        $cloneStmnt = $connection->prepare($cloneQuery);
        $cloneStmnt->execute($dataCl);
        endwhile;          
        header('location: ./../posts_archive.php');   
 }
```

i have tried to echo the title etc. everywhere in the code and it does work. all the database values are correct also. i really am on a dead end to why it does not fetch the data and then insert it again to duplicate it.

this is the code before the external function: ( the switch case ):

```
     include('./../../../configs/db-config.php'); 
     //here i link to the database connection
     bulkOperation($connection);
     function bulkOperation($connection){
     if(isset($_POST['bulkPosts'])):
       if(!isset($_POST['checkboxItem']) || 
        empty($_POST['checkboxItem'])):
            header('location: ./../posts_archive.php');
            die();             
       endif;
       $checkboxItem = $_POST['checkboxItem'];
        foreach($checkboxItem as $value):
            $bulkValue = $_POST['bulkPosts'];
            $data = [
                'value' => $value,
            ];
            switch($bulkValue):
                case 'archive':
                    $bulkQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_status = 0 WHERE post_id = :value";
                    $connection->prepare($bulkQuery)->execute($data);
                        header('location: ./../posts_archive.php');
                break;
                case 'publish':
                    $bulkQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_status = 1 WHERE post_id = :value";
                    $connection->prepare($bulkQuery)->execute($data);
                        header('location: ./../posts_archive.php');
                break;
                case 'highlight':
                    $bulkQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_status = 2 WHERE post_id = :value";
                    $connection->prepare($bulkQuery)->execute($data);    
                        header('location: ./../posts_archive.php');        
                break;
                case 'delete':
                    $bulkQuery = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = :value";
                    $connection->prepare($bulkQuery)- 
    >execute($data);
                        header('location: ./../posts_archive.php');
                break;
                case 'duplicate':
                    $bulkQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id 
    = :value";
                    duplicateBulk($bulkQuery, $connection, $data);
                break;
                default:
                    #redirect back to archive_posts
            break;
        endswitch;
    endforeach;         
endif;    
}
```

so this is the situation i have explained short:
fetch data in page1. page1 add option to send post_id to page2 , in page2 check if select == duplicate, if select == duplicate, make a query and start a new function in page2 also.
in the new function, which is out of the foreach loop and switch , fetch the data , and try to insert it again. ( this happens outside of the foreach loop where i loop through all post_id's (:value) , but inside the foreach loop i call the function so this shouldnt be a problem i think.

if someone knows what i do wrong, please tell me i really am on a dead end and do not know what to do...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your database allow you to have a second post with the same post_id? Surely that would be unique, and your duplicate post would need its own id?

Comment: post_id has AUTO_INCREMENT , so yeah if it would reach the database it would be the ID+1

Comment: Not if you send it a value, it won't. Try your insert query without the post id and let it assign a new one. Or check after your insert query for errors, see why it says it couldn't insert. Would it want to be post_id + 1? What if you're duplicating a post from a year ago?

Comment: WOW... i did not know that, and yes now it works :) thank you.

Comment: Great, glad it's sorted.

Comment: @droopsnoot there wouldn't be an error, for some unknown  reason they are using IGNORE to suppress such errors

Comment: Oh yes, good point.